# What to use to replace StringMap in the latest version of Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I use StringMap of Gson 2.2, but seems in the latest version Gson, it is removed, then what class should I use to replace it ? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with HashMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StringMap` [source code](https://github.com/google/gson/commit/14f16e2d0c3c60338d69a3e0f653b8b876fdc1be#diff-30ed932f4f231b35698a715d20447d4c) told (as well as its source code [bundle](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.2/) does) it was derived from `LinkedHashMap`. Just use `LinkedHashMap<String, ...>` in order to preserve the behavior of your code that is using the string map class and follow up the original design of the string map class (it preserved the order of JSON properties).

Definitely, a nice example of not using anything from library internal packages (`com.google.gson.internal` sounds the same).

Comment: Actually, StringMap seems to be replaced by LinkedTreeMap which does not inherit from LinkedHashMap, but from AbstractMap.

Answer (score 1):

com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap